# Is "my preference towards exact sciences" legitimate?

Tags: phrases

Do you consider the following phrase legitimate?

> my preference towards exact sciences

Is there a more accurate way to say it?

Comment: Written instances for *preference towards* in NGrams virtually [flatline](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preference+for%2Cpreference+towards&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) against the standard *preference for*.

Comment: It's valid except that, when used as a preposition, I believe it's always "toward". With an s, "towards", it's only valid as an adjective meaning "soon to come" or "apt to learn". The adjective usages is also valid without the s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say "my preference ***for*** exact sciences".